# Cannot read property 'stateChangeExpr' of null at _parseAnimationStateTransition

Tags: angular, datatable, primeng

Getting this error when try to use ngprime datatable.

```
Cannot read property 'stateChangeExpr' of null     at _parseAnimationStateTransition
```

Any ideas? someone with the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

update your angular packages to 4.0+ can solve the problem
angular is now on version 4.0
and don't forget to update angular-cli

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5503